# How to Add a Flutter Module as a On Demand Module in Native Android Application

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I have a Flutter Module and I want to add it as a On Demand Module in Native Android App, so that I can download the flutter module only when I require it. So by default Flutter module will not be included at install time. On demand module can be used for Android Module using Dynamic feature, can we use the same feature for Flutter module or any other way is there?

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter we have [Deferred Components](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/deferred-components). This allows apps to reduce install apk size and download features and assets when needed by the user.